# SQL dropping selected row from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and do not understand how to drop rows from a table. I have this:

```
select distinct course.course_id, title, dept_name, credits
from course, section
where course.course_id not in (select course_id from section);
```

and when this runs I get the row:
`BIO-399   "Computational Biology"   Biology   4`

Now, how do I delete this from the "course" table? I cannot search for this specific class because this code needs to be able to work on any table with different classes.

I tried

```
delete from course where course_id in
   (select distinct course.course_id, title, dept_name, credits
   from course, section
   where course.course_id not in (select course_id from section));
```

but this does not work. It says "operand should contain 1 column(s)", but I want to delete a row not a column. I have looked at several answers to similar problems and tried to emulate the answer but i am not have luck.

Comment: From which table are the columns in the Select-list? If all columns are from `course` there's no need to join to `section`. The Select is not coded correctly, there's no join-condition between `course` and `section`, resulting in a `cross join` (that's probably why you added the `distinct`). This is the correct version: `select course.course_id, title, dept_name, credits
    from course join section
      on course.course_id = section.course_id
    where course.course_id not in (select course_id from section);`

Comment: *operand should contain 1 column(s)* refers to your scalar comparison `WHERE course_id IN (...)`.  What's inside the `()` is the referenced operand and this specific error is because you are selecting multiple columns even though you're comparing to only one column (course_id).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this by using **join concept of the SQL**. Here we will use **left join**.

```
delete course from 
course left join section on course.course_id = section.course_id 
where course.course_id = NULL;
```

Note: here I have assumed course_id is present in both the tables like a foreign key, If not can you share the schema of both tables for more clarity?

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
delete from course where course_id in
(select distinct course.course_id
from course, section
where course.course_id not in (select course_id from section));
```

From what I have understood, you don't need to join course and section for this query.

Please try this and see if you are getting same results:

```
select distinct course.course_id
from course
where course.course_id not in (select course_id from section)
```

If yes, then use this query to delete:

```
delete from course where course_id in
(select distinct course.course_id
from (select * from course) as c
where c.course_id not in (select course_id from section));
```

Comment: That third section of SQL code gives me the error `You can't specify target table 'course' for update in FROM clause`, which is an error I've seen before and don't know how to work around.

Comment: Does the 2nd query give the result as you want?

Comment: the 2nd query is good I think, it returns bio399 and a null beneath it. On the third query, first it yelled at me for being in a safe update mode, and when I went into unsafe mode it says `cannot update or delete a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`. I am trying to figure out the logic

Comment: There might be a row in with null value in course_id column in course table. Also check if 3rd query is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SQL` should be like this

```
DELETE FROM `course` WHERE `course_id`="BIO-399" AND `title`="Computational Biology" AND `credits` ="4";
```

**breakdown :**

```
Delete from table-name where condition
```

Above will delete rows from table `table-name` which satisfies the conditions provided after `where` clause

condition is `column-name = value` .

Comment: that would be good, but I need to make this able to work for multiple databases, where I'm not guaranteed to even have a BIO-399 to delete

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
FROM course 
WHERE course_id="BIO-399" AND title = "Computational Biology" AND credits ="4";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists school_course,school_section;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table school_course (id int, name varchar(2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table school_section(id int, cid int, name varchar(2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into school_course values (1,'c1'),(2,'c2');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into school_section values (1,1,'s1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select sc.*, ss.*
    -> from school_course sc
    -> left join school_section ss on ss.cid = sc.id;
+------+------+------+------+------+
| id   | name | id   | cid  | name |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | c1   |    1 |    1 | s1   |
|    2 | c2   | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> delete sc
    -> from school_course sc
    -> left join school_section ss on ss.cid = sc.id
    -> where ss.cid is null;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select sc.*, ss.*
    -> from school_course sc
    -> left join school_section ss on ss.cid = sc.id;
+------+------+------+------+------+
| id   | name | id   | cid  | name |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | c1   |    1 |    1 | s1   |
+------+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```